# Add commas to a string

Tags: string, split, lua

How can I add commas to separate text items inside a string

Let's assume I have this string:

```
local s = "some text here"
```

I want to convert that string (without white space) to:

```
local t = "some,text,here"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the gsub()

```
t = string.gsub(s, " ", ",")
```

Comment: most welcome :)

You can abbreviate it to:

    t=s:gsub(" ",",")

Comment: If there are more than one white space between text, there will be two commas. It's fine with me and works as I wanted, but is there any way to treat white spaces between two words as one and just separate them with only one comma?

Comment: If two's the only problem then t=s:gsub("  ",",") will do the trick (2 spaces in first quotes) usually such problems are solved with regex which is not available in lua and I'm not aware of a decent workaround.

Comment: The first argument to `:gsub` is _always_ interpreted as a Lua pattern (which is a regex). So, be sure to escape characters in a literal string, when that's what you intend.

Comment: @TomBlodget Thank you. The reason why I needed to do that is because I'm using the string as keywords for this API: exmpale.com/api/searchOnDemand?prettyprint=1&keywords=hello,there